# Emoji в Bitmap после вращения. Android

Tags: android, view, bitmap, rotation

У меня есть view на Canvas которого нарисован StaticLayout с текстом, в котором присутствует emoji, и к canvas был применен метод canvas.rotate(45).

```
StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(contentText, textPaint, (int) (container.getWidth() * container.getScale()), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER, 1.0f, 0.0f, false);
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(45);
layout.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

на вью отображается отлично, 
[image: отображается на view]
но вот когда я пытаюсь из View получить Bitmap,

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(),
            view.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas bitmapCanvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    bitmapCanvas.drawColor(
            Color.TRANSPARENT,
            PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    bitmapCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
    view.draw(bitmapCanvas);

    return bitmap;
}
```

на Bitmap текст отображается как положено по диагонали, а вот emoji также занимает символ по диагонали, но отображается горизонтально. 
[image: а это уже отображается Bitmap]

Может кто-то знает в чем может быть причина того что emoji не переносятся на Bitmap под наклоном?